# ASP.NET MVC загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Доброго,
не судите строго, в asp.net я новичок. Есть форма

```html
@model BooksCatalogue.Models.booksCatalogue

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Новая книга</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr/>
        <table width="100%">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            <tr>
                <td width="10%" valign="top">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <img id="show" src=data:image/png;base64,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 width="170" height="170"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="40%" valign="top">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, "Название", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.author, "Автор", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.author, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.author, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.genre, "Жанр", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.genre, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.genre, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cover, "Обложка", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="files" type="file" accept=".jpg" name="files" />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cover, "")
                            <script>
                                function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    var file = evt.target.files;
                                    var img = document.getElementById('show');
                                    reader.onload = function (e) { img.src = e.target.result };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);
                                }
                                document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, "Аннотация", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="90%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contents, "Содержание", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contents, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contents, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="sbmt" type="submit" value="Добавить книгу" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться", "Index")
</div>
```

и есть контролер (пока решил не заморачиваться и сделал один для всех форм). Форму добавления новой книги обрабатывают два метода

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFile files)
    {
        var path = "";
        if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filename = "createimage.jpg";
            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), filename);
            files.SaveAs(path);
        }

        try
        {
            var context = new CatalogueEntities();
            context.booksCatalogue.Add(new booksCatalogue
            {
                id = context.booksCatalogue.Count() + 1,
                author = collection["author"],
                contents = collection["contents"],
                cover = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path),
                description = collection["description"],
                genre = collection["genre"],
                title = collection["title"]
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation(
                        "Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                        validationError.PropertyName,
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Внимание, вопрос)) Что я делаю не так? Метод public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFile files) не перехватывает files(всегда null). Мне кажется что проблема в самой форме, но в чем именно она заключается не мог никак понять. Замечу, что необходимо загружать фото именно при нажатии на кнопку "добавить", дополнительных форм быть тоже не должно. Благодарствую за внимание, господа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете тип `HttpPostedFile`. А на самом деле `MVC` создает экземпляр класса `HttpPostedFileWrapper`, который является [обверткой класса](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Abstractions/HttpPostedFileWrapper.cs,2d580e0e3dae70ed) `HttpPostedFile`.
Но лучше использовать базовый класс - это `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
// ...
}
```

Почему так сделали? Я не могу точно сказать, но читал, что в первых версиях создавался экземпляр класса `HttpPostedFile`. Но из-за того что класс запечатанный, он представлял трудности для тестирования. Поэтому создали абстрактный класс `HttpPostedFileBase`, а реализовали его через `HttpPostedFileWrapper`, который является обверткой над классом `HttpPostedFile`.

Comment: потому что внимательности не хватает видимо. Спасибо огромное. Заработало.